# Why is the payload part needed for JWT auth?

Tags: authentication, jwt

**header(grey), payload(red), signature(light green)**

[image]

This is a question about authentication protocols. The server side has the secret key below, which means it can recognises who the client is by decrypting the signature. So it is not necessary that the payload below is exposed in http packets.

Or, in case there is a secret_key for each user at server side, the payload is needed. But for the case, the server has to store each secret key for each user, which means this is not the case of "stateless" protocol. However, I heard that JWT auth is "stateless".

Answer (score 0):

the server side has no track for each JWT token for each user, 
instead, when a user sends a request with a JWT token it is added as `authentication:"the JWT token go here"` into the headers.

Then the server receives this request it looks inside of the authentication headers and decodes this token with a secret key that only the server know, once the token is decoded then the server look if the data inside of the token this can be a user id or something else, and look if the user id is valid.

Comment: Yes. the secret key is only one and kept secretly at the server side, and without the payload, the server can't check if the token is forged. right?

Comment: If  the headers have not the authorization token, then the server discards the payload and send an `error: you have to provide an authorization header`

Comment: Then, I wonder if the header value is always the same or not for every token for every user for every JWT token. I am referring to the headers in the picture not general http headers like you.

Comment: The header values in your picture are always the same because this is a secret_key encode if you change the secret_key, then the header value change.

This header is encoded with the payload, is because that  the JWT token is different for each user,

Comment: It looks like there are misunderstanding on what a JWS is. When using JWS (signed token) the key on server side is used to check the signature. There is no encryption process here. The header does not change necessarily if you change the key and it is not encoded with the payload.